# Can I define a numbered Enum?

Tags: apex

I'd like to write the following:

```
public enum OrderType
{
    Coop = 0,
    Normal = 1,
    Package = 2,
    SubInvoicing = 3,
}
```

It doesn't seem like it's supported.  Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Unfortunately not, but as long as you're happy with not being able to define the numbers yourself, and 0 based counting is good enough then you can use the [enum method `ordinal()` which lets you know the index of the enum value you're currently referencing](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_enum.htm).

So if you declared your enum like so:

```
public enum OrderType
{
    Coop,
    Normal,
    Package,
    SubInvoicing
}
```

Then you calling `OrderType.Normal.ordinal()` would return an integer with value `1`. Of course if you do need to specify numbers a somewhat hacky way would be to add placeholder entries within your list, but depending on the numbers you need that could get a bit crazy. Another alternative might be a public map:

```
public class OrderTypeMap
{
  private static Map<String, Integer> typeMap = new Map<String, Integer>
  {
    'Coop' => 0,
    'Normal' => 1,
    'Package' => 2,
    'SubInvoicing' => 3
  };

  public Integer Value(String s)
  {
    return typeMap.get(s);
  }
}
```

You could even combine that with an enum (if you really want the enum rather than a string) and use the `name()` enum method to pass into the map:

```
Integer i = OrderTypeMap.Value(OrderType.Normal.name());
```

Comment: Thanks.  I was hoping I was doing something wrong. So there is no way to have an enum with bitwise flags there then?

Comment: Not really — I miss those myself coming from a C background!

Answer (score 1):

As near as I can tell the best you can do is:

```
public class Foo {
    public enum OrderType
    {
        Coop,
        Normal,
        Package,
        SubInvoicing
    }

    public Map<OrderType,Integer> OrderTypeMap = ( new Map<OrderType,Integer>{
        Coop => 1,
        Normal => 2,
        Package => 3,
        SubInvoicing => 4 } );

...
}
```

Note: The parenthesis are just so the developer console will not mangle the indenting too badly.

I know this is not the solution you were looking for, but it seems like the simplest one.  More complicated is you define a class instead:

```
public class Foo {
    public static OrderTypeEnum OrderType = new OrderTypeEnum();

    public class OrderTypeEnum
    {
        public Integer Coop { get { return 1; } }
        public Integer Normal { get { return 2; } }
        public Integer Package { get { return 3; } }
        public Integer SubInvoicing { get { return 4; } }
    }

...
}
```

Neither does exactly what you want, but both come close.   In the first example, you can do things like:

```
Foo.OrderType ot = Foo.OrderType.Coop;
if(Foo.OrderTypeMap.get(ot) == 1)
...
```

In the second:

```
Integer ot = Foo.OrderType.Coop;
if(ot == Foo.OrderType.Coop)
...
```

Neither is doing exactly what you want, but they are close to what you want.

Even closer, but even more complicated:

```
public class Foo {
    public static OrderTypeEnum OrderType = new OrderTypeEnum(null);

    public class OrderTypeEnum
    {
        final Integer ordinal;
        public OrderTypeEnum(Integer ordinal) { this.ordinal = ordinal; }
        public OrderTypeEnum Coop { get { return new OrderTypeEnum(1); } }
        public OrderTypeEnum Normal { get { return new OrderTypeEnum(2); } }
        public OrderTypeEnum Package { get { return new OrderTypeEnum(3); } }
        public OrderTypeEnum SubInvoicing { get { return new OrderTypEnum(4); } }
        public Boolean equals(Object that) {
            return (that instanceof OrderTypeEnum)?((OrderTypeEnum)that.oridinal == ordinal):(that == ordinal);
        }
        public Integer hashCode() {return ordinal;}
        public Integer ordinal() {return ordinal;}
    }

...
}
```

You can now treat this almost like an Enum.  e.g.

```
Foo.OrderTypeEnum ot = Foo.OrderType.Coop;
if(ot.ordinal() == 1)
...
if(ot.equals(1))
...
if(ot.equals(Foo.OrderType.Coop))
...
```

A few things won't work though, like using these in switch statements.  Care needs to be taken when using the equality operator, ==.  Because ot == 1 will work, but 1 == ot will not.

Really it is just an issue how complicated are you willing to get to replicate the usage scenario you have in mind.